# In Ember, can I yield input tag to component and not break my form?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am thinking maybe I found a bug in EmberJS yield function.

What I want to achieve is, one component for forms, were I yield additional input tags, if they are needed. My example is more complicated, but I reproduced the "bug" in [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c56da15b0258d1e04017).

Basically, I have component:

#### form-component/template.hbs

```
<form {{action 'componentAction' on='submit'}}>
  {{yield}}
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And I want to yield input tag there

#### application/template.hbs

```
{{#form-component
  action="controllerAction"}}
  {{input value=name placeholder='Name'}}
{{/form-component}}
```

And as you can see, it doesn't work in the Twiddle. (It should update the text below the form to your input)

But if I move the input `{{input value=name placeholder='Name'}}` from `application/template.hbs` to component, it works:

#### UPDATED form-component/template.hbs

```
<form {{action 'componentAction' on='submit'}}>
  {{yield}}
  {{input value=name placeholder='Name'}}
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

#### UPDATED application/template.hbs

```
{{#form-component
  action="controllerAction"}}
{{/form-component}}
```

Is it a bug, or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: That's not a bug. The value of your input will be set in the component or controller you declare it. If you create the input in application/template.hbs, the value will be set in the template controller. If you create it in the component, the value will be set in the form-component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the value in the form component, you can have something like this:

```
//form-component/template.hbs
{{#form-component
  action="controllerAction" as |myForm|}}
  {{input value=myForm.name placeholder='Name'}}
{{/form-component}}


//application/template.hbs
<form {{action 'componentAction' on='submit'}}>
    {{yield this}}
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you know if one can do this while using [this method](https://coderwall.com/p/qkk2zq/components-with-structured-markup-in-ember-js-v1-10) to get multiple yields? I mean something like `{{yield body this}}`